# Include custom URL prefix for languages in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, django-1.11

I am trying to include the country codes as well while implementing django language translation apart from the usual language codes like `en` and `ar` which would be appended to the url's. I am trying to acheive something like this

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/uae-ar/1.10/howto/       # this will be Arabic
https://docs.djangoproject.com/uae-fr/1.10/howto/       # this will be French
```

Below is my settings file variables

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGES = (
   ('en', _('English')),
   ('uae-ar', _('Arabic')),
   ('uae-fr', _('French')),
)
```

I would like to know the best practice of implementing this method. Please do let me know if I am missing out on anything here.